# How to select input Value

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.6

```
<div class="lang_selection"><input id="lang_0" name="language[]" 
value="0" type="checkbox"><label for="lang_0">English</label> 
</div>

<div class="lang_selection"><input id="lang_25" name="language[]" 
 value="25" type="checkbox"><label for="lang_25">Arabic</label> 
</div>

<div class="lang_selection"><input id="lang_22" name="language[]" 
 value="22" type="checkbox"><label for="lang_22">Portuguese- 
 Brazil</label></div>

<div class="lang_selection"><input id="lang_23" name="language[]" 
value="23" type="checkbox"><label for="lang_23">Bulgarian</label> 
</div>

<div class="lang_selection">
<input id="lang_19" name="language[]" value="19" type="checkbox"> 
<label for="lang_19">Czech</label>
</div>
```

I tried this code

```
value = soup.find('input', {'name': 'language[]'}).get('value')
```

but give me error:'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I want to get a array list of the value number `[0,25,22,23,19]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector, so it will become one liner:

```
print([int(i['value']) for i in soup.select(r'input[name^=language]') if 'value' in i.attrs])
```

Prints:

```
[0, 25, 22, 23, 19]
```

`input[name^=language]` will select all `<input>` tags, that the attribute name begins with `language`.

Comment: nice and neat! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need this perhaps:

```
rangeLen = len(soup.findAll(attrs={"name" : "language[]"}))
language = soup.findAll(attrs={"name" : "language[]"})
valueList = list()

for i in range(rangeLen):
    valueList.append(int(language[i]['value']))

print(valueList)
```

Output:

```
[0, 25, 22, 23, 19]
```